# Java Netbeans gui jframe form button control

Tags: java, netbeans

so I am writing a program using netbean's gui editor and I have some text that cycles through every time I hit the continue button. i did this by changing 1 label in the continue listener, but after I run out of text I want to bring up the programs main menu by removing the label, and removing the continue button. I know how to do this in the code, but i don't know how to cycle through the gui editor in order to get to the blank space in order to create my main menu. any ideas? or tips to fix this? or do i need to set all of the buttons on top of each other and then make them invisible? because I feel like there is a better way than that to fix this problem... also its my first time using the netbeans gui editor, before i always just did it manually

here is an exerpt of my code normally, but I want to know how to perform the last iteration in the editor

```
//assume that begin count is intialized to 0 in the begining 


class beginListener implements 
{   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            beginCount++;

        if(beginCount==1){
             frame.setSize(450,200);
           beginText.setText("random text1");

          }
         else if(beginCount==2)
          {  
              frame.setSize(300,200);
              beginText.setText("random text2");
          }  
          else if(beginCount==3)
          { frame.setSize(300,200);
            beginText.setText("random text3");


          }  
          else if(beginCount==4)
          {frame.setSize(250,200);
           beginText.setText("random text4");

          }  
          else if(beginCount==5)
          { frame.setSize(300,200);
             beginText.setText("random text5");


          }  
          else if(beginCount==6)
          {  frame.setSize(450,200);
              beginText.setText("random text6");


          }
             else if(beginCount==7)
          { frame.setSize(250,200);
            beginText.setText("random text7");  


          }  
             else if(beginCount==8)
          {  frame.setSize(300,200);
        beginText.setText("random text8");

          }  
            else{frame.setSize(300,300);

                 output.setText(null);
                 beginText.setText(null);

                 frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                 addAll();
                   //addAll() adds the menu
```

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: This might seem blunt, so I'm sorry for that, but, I would highly encourage you to code you UI's in the future until you have a firm understand how to make complex and dynamic UI's by hand. Until you can do this, you won't understand how and when a GUI editor is a good tool as well as how to solve problems with it.  In my experience, the GUI editor generally encourages bad design which is difficult to manage

Comment: I already coded it, now im trying to figure out how to do it in the editor so i can streamline the process